# Selenium Python Selector Returning Too Many Values

Tags: python, selenium, web-scraping, css-selectors

wondering if anyone can give me some advice for using Selenium with Python for webscraping.

I need to get the number of elements with a certain class on a page, and I have it working well with

```
driver=webdriver.PhantomJS()
driver.get('https://www.somerandomsite.com/1')
number_of_elements = len(driver.find_elements_by_class_name('some_class'))
```

this gets the right number of elements every time.

But now I want to define a function so it can scrape multiple webpages - say https://www.somerandomsite.com/1 to https://www.somerandomsite.com/10

So I do

```
driver=webdriver.PhantomJS()
def my_func(start,end)
    while start <= end:
        driver.get('https://www.somerandomsite.com/'+str(start))
        number_of_elements = len(driver.find_elements_by_class_name('some_class'))
        start += 1
```

Theoretically, this should move onto the next page, and retrieve the number of classes that I want in that page. However, it works fine for the first page, but subsequent pages yield a number of elements that's either equal to the number of elements of the previous page plus that of the current page, or that sum minus 1. If I use an xpath instead of a class name selector I get the exact same results.

Also, if I try to access any elements that are in that longer list, it throws an error since only the values on that page actually exist. So I have no idea how it's getting that longer list if the elements on it don't even exist. (For example, if there are 8 elements on page one and 5 elements on page two, when it gets to page two it'll say there are 12 or 13 elements. If I access elements 1-5 they all return values, but trying to call the sixth element or higher will cause a NoSuchElementException.)

Anyone know why this might be happening?

EDIT: I've narrowed it down a bit more, hopefully this helps. Sorry I was off in the initial question.

```
driver=webdriver.PhantomJS()
def my_func(start,end)
    while start <= end:
        driver.get('https://www.somerandomsite.com/'+str(start))
        number_of_elements = len(driver.find_elements_by_class_name('some_class'))
        start += 1
```

So the above code actually works. However, when I then navigate to another page that also has elements of 'some_class', and then continue looping, it adds the number of elements from the previous page to the current page.

So my code's like this:

```
driver=webdriver.PhantomJS()
def my_func(start,end)
    while start <= end:
        driver.get('https://www.somerandomsite.com/'+str(start))
        number_of_elements = len(driver.find_elements_by_class_name('some_class'))
        print(number_of_elements)
        driver.get('https://www.somerandomsite.com/otherpage')
        start += 1

my_func(1,2)
```

So let's say https://www.somerandomsite.com/1 has 8 elements of class 'some_class', https://www.somerandomsite.com/otherpage has 7 elements of class 'some_class', and https://www.somerandomsite.com/2 has 10 elements of class 'some_class'.

When I run the above code, it'll print 8, then 17. If I don't navigate to the other page, and run

```
driver=webdriver.PhantomJS()
def my_func(start,end)
    while start <= end:
        driver.get('https://www.somerandomsite.com/'+str(start))
        number_of_elements = len(driver.find_elements_by_class_name('some_class'))
        start += 1
```

So the above code actually works. However, when I then navigate to another page that also has elements of 'some_class', and then continue looping, it adds the number of elements from the previous page to the current page.

So my code's like this:

```
driver=webdriver.PhantomJS()
def my_func(start,end)
    while start <= end:
        driver.get('https://www.somerandomsite.com/'+str(start))
        number_of_elements = len(driver.find_elements_by_class_name('some_class'))
        print(number_of_elements)
        start += 1

my_func(1,2)
```

it'll print 8 then 10, as I want it to. I'm not sure why it's counting elements on two pages at once, and only if I get that other page beforehand.

EDIT2: So I've gotten it working by navigating to a page on a different server and then returning to the page I want. Weird, but I'll use it. If anyone has any ideas on why it doesn't work if I don't though I'd still love to understand the problem better.

Comment: Can you share more code, desired output and exception log as for now it's not quite clear what exactly is wrong with your code? Note that provided function is senseless as it doesn't print or return values, so  `number_of_elements` will be re-defined on each page

Comment: Sure thing, sorry - hopefully the new edit provides enough detail.

Answer (score 1):

Difficult to tell what - if at all - the problem is as you don't provide the necessary details to replicate what you're describing.

IMHO a function is overkill for this simple task. Just toss it and create the loop. In general I'd put the loop outside.

Also you need a function call for this to do anything at all - and a return statement.

In general for similar stuff I'd put the loop outside the function.

Like so:

```
def my_func(driver, count):
    driver.get('https://www.somerandomsite.com/%d' % count)
    number_of_elements = len(driver.find_elements_by_class_name('some_class'))
    return number_of_elements

driver=webdriver.PhantomJS() 
total_element_count = 0
count = 1
while count < 1000: # or whatever number you need
    number_of_elements = my_func(driver, count)
    total_element_count += number_of_elements
    print("[*] Elements for iteration %d: %d" % (count, number_of_elements))
    print("[*] Total count so far: %d" % total_element_count)
    count +=1
```

Comment: Sorry, I've added more details if that helps. I'll also try the external loop and see if that works, cheers!

Comment: Unfortunately I just tried the external loop, and no luck. Same results as before.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at

```
number_of_elements = len(driver.find_elements_by_class_name('some_class'))
```

You asign len of elements on each iteration, but instead you need to sum them, so your code should look like:

```
driver=webdriver.PhantomJS()
def my_func(start,end):
    count = 0
    while start <= end:
        driver.get('https://www.somerandomsite.com/'+str(start))
        count += len(driver.find_elements_by_class_name('some_class'))
        start += 1
```